# Classifying the critical points of $\arctan(1+y^2-x^2y+x^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

In the problem I am asked to classify and find the critical points  of the function $$\arctan(1+y^2-x^2y+x^2)$$
I solved the question initially by differentiating the arctan(x,y) with derivatives $$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac {1} {(1+y^2-x^2y+x^2)^2}(-2xy+2x)$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac {1} {(1+y^2-x^2y+x^2)^2}(2y-x^2)
$$
because it is a composite function but my professor finds the solution only by studying the argument inside the arctangent hence using
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=(-2xy+2x)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=(2y-x^2)
$$
I have not asked him because tutoring in the university is now closed.

Comment: arctangent is a monotone function, so for any function $f$ the critical points of $\arctan(f)$ are the critical points of $f$.

Comment: oh my thank you for the reminder hahaha